# Bone (Armature) ghosting problem

Tags: animation, armature

There is a problem with armature ghosting. It's not shown in viewport.
Onion skins are work fine. Motion path works with geometry, but doesn't work with bones.. 
What can it be? a Bug? Nvidia driver problem? Am I missed something? Some addon blocks it?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to play it in pose mode?
worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

[image: abracadabra]

motion paths work like this. Although for some reason in this example head and tails were switched by machine. could be bug.

Comment: yeah, motion path works for bones from this menu, and via panel too after that, but ghost still is not...